# Mocking a function inside the method being tested

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I want to test a method inside my code that executes a set of different functions... and one of those inner functions when called, sends an email.

What I want is to avoid this function from sending emails when running the tests. Is there a way to achieve this?

I want to run away from things like the following in my code:

```
if (app.get('env') !== 'test')
```

I use *Promises*, and the function I want to test looks like this:

```
var emailService = require('../path/to/custom/service.js');

// This is the method I want to test
exports.sendKeyByEmail = function(email) {
  return _getByEmail(email) // finds a user given an email
    .then(function(user) {
      if (!user) {
        throw new UserNotFoundError();
      }
      user.key = _generateKey(); // generates a random hash
      return user.save(); // saves the user (mongoose stuff...)
    })
    .then(function(user) {
      // This is what I would like to mock during testing
      return emailService.sendKey(user.email, user.key);
    });
}
```

The `emailService.sendKey()` method is the one that sends an email and returns a Promise. During testing, I would like it to just return a fulfilled Promise `Promise.resolve()` directly, instead of really sending an email.

Comment: This is the kind of problem that's solved with Dependency Injection - where in your test you swap out a real implementation of `emailService` with one that just pretends it's sent the mail.

Comment: @Starscream1984 that's the concept I had in mind, thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

[I answered a question just like this yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042286/how-do-you-stub-private-functions-when-unit-testing-a-revealing-module/36042433#36042433): rather than combining the two concerns into a private method or hidden function, separate them into two classes and pass the email implementation into the outer class. This will allow you to provide a mock `emailService` during testing and solve your problem quite neatly.

When setting that up, I'm a fan of constructor dependency injection, as it gives you the benefits of DI without doing anything tricky (like reflection). With ES6 parameters, you can also provide a default for when you aren't mocking anything out.

Very roughly, you could do something like:

```
var defaultEmailService = require('../path/to/custom/service.js');

// This is the method I want to test
exports.sendKeyByEmail = function(email, emailService = defaultEmailService) {
  return _getByEmail(email) // finds a user given an email
    .then(function(user) {
      if (!user) {
        throw new UserNotFoundError();
      }
      user.key = _generateKey(); // generates a random hash
      return user.save(); // saves the user (mongoose stuff...)
    })
    .then(function(user) {
      // This is what I would like to mock during testing
      return emailService.sendKey(user.email, user.key);
    });
}
```

In your test, simply pass a mock `emailService` that returns predictable results without touching the network.

Comment: I was just wondering... this sounds great for doing unit testing, but what about API testing? Say I want to test my API method (using `superset`) to check correct response http-codes, and I want to simulate as well the emailService... As I am not testing the `sendEmail()` method directly calling it, would this be also possible? Do you get what I mean? :-)

Comment: @charliebrownie Mocking out your API is good for small tests (unit tests). You can occasionally mock (or proxy) the network classes used by the API and test error handling, but you may need to set up a test instance of the API or something along those lines for your larger tests (integration testing).